# truffle serve throws the below mentioned error?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

> ```
> :\blockchain\truffle\demo\mortgage-blockchain-demo>truffle serve
> erving static assets in .\build on port 8080...
> ebuilding...
> :\Users\Mabel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:220
> 48
>  return (new fsevents(path)).on('fsevent', callback).start();
>          ^
>
> ypeError: fsevents is not a constructor
>    at createFSEventsInstance (C:\Users\Mabel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\t
> uffle\build\cli.bundled.js:220548:11)
>    at setFSEventsListener (C:\Users\Mabel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truf
> le\build\cli.bundled.js:220602:16)
>    at FSWatcher.FsEventsHandler._watchWithFsEvents (C:\Users\Mabel\AppData\Roam
> ng\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:220766:16)
>    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mabel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tr
> ffle\build\cli.bundled.js:220900:25)
>    at LOOP (fs.js:1758:14)
>    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
>    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
> ```

kindly help me in resolving the issue . I am running on a windows 7 machine .

trying to do ethereum truffle setup.

Comment: See https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/463

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the `FsEvents` when not used:

- C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js

  // if (!FsEventsHandler.canUse())

  opts.useFsEvents = false;

Steps:

- `truffle compile && truffle build && truffle migrate  && truffle serve`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove/off this below code in //Users/**abc/projectFolder/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js

---

function createFSEventsInstance(path, callback) {

//return (new fsevents(path)).on('fsevent', callback).start();

}

Answer (score 0):

scene：

```
 using create-react-app 
 /Users/**abc/projectFolder/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js
```

Solution：

```
Temporarily //return (new fsevents(path)).on('fsevent', callback).start();
```